# Como fazer um search com .serialize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esse **[Search/Serialize JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thiago_diniz/4c45bcuw/12/)**, só que eu não queria que ele pegasse o nome do `select`, somente o `value` do `option` e fizesse o search.

Tem como "ignorar" o `name` e usar só o `value` ?

Eis o código:

```
    var host = "http://www.rs1.com.br/";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#send').click(function(){
            var variables = $('#form').find('campo').serialize();
            var destination = host + variables.replace('=','/');
            $('#link').html(destination)
            window.open(destination);      
        });
    });

<form id="form">
    <select>
        <option value="tutto-moto" class="campo">Tutto</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="Acessorio" class="campo">Tutto</option>
    </select>    
    <select>
        <option value="produto" class="campo">Iphone+4s</option>
    </select>   
</form>
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn">Buscar</button>
```

Comment: Você quer algo do tipo `http://www.rs1.com.br/tutto-moto/Acessorio/produto` é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo, eu não deixei na ordem exata pra trazer os resultados mas é essa a ideia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meu conhecimento de JS/jQuery não é tão amplo, mas dá pra fazer assim **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4c45bcuw/14/)**.

Basicamente é só percorrer os elementos em vez de usar `serialize`, e tratar a string. Agora se tem como fazer com `serialize` eu não sei.

```
$('#send').click(function(){
    var variables = '';
    // Percorre todos os campos campos dentro da tag select com a classe campo
    $('#form select').find('.campo').each(function(){
       variables += $(this).attr('value')+'/'; // Concatena o valor do option
    });
    var destination = host + variables;
    $('#link').html(destination)
    window.open(destination);
});
```

Comment: era isso mesmo que eu queria haha :D obrigado, só sabe me dizer como eu faço para que o botão buscar faça o search dentro da mesma página sem abrir outra ? Pois do jeito que ele está abre uma nova aba.

Comment: Usa `windows.location.href = destination;` em vez de `window.open(destination);`